# How to use EditText to go another activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In an Android studio activity I want to use the EditText input to go to a second activity, my code works, but I have to press twice for this to work, how can I correct this to only press once

```
 editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
 editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);

 public void addListenerOnButton() {
    editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String text = editText.getText().toString();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Calculated.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("mytext",text);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping your EditText inside other view (RelativeLayout / LinearLayout) and set a click listener on that view; whereas keep the EditText disabled to avoid getting focus.

Comment: What is `addListenerOnButton()`?

Answer (score 1):

Why did you wrap the listener of the `EditText` inside another listener?
Change to this:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);

editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Calculated.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("mytext",text);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

this way when you click on the `EditText` you will start the other activity.

If you want to click a `Button` to start the activity, say with id `button`, then set the listener on the `Button`:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Calculated.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("mytext",text);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by using the EditText input to go to a second activity ?

If you want a click logic, use a Button.

If you want to use the 'DONE' button of the EditText:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),Calculated.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("mytext",text);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

On your layout.xml, on your editText you need to add:

```
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use Button instead of Edittext but still if you want;

```
EditText edtClick;

edtClick = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtClickActivity);

        edtClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

That works.